# SQL order by two column, omit if second column doesn't meet the order

Tags: sql

Let's say we have next data

```
id |    date    | price
------------------------
1  | 10-09-2016 |   200    
2  | 11-09-2016 |   190    
3  | 12-09-2016 |   210    
4  | 13-09-2016 |   220    
5  | 14-09-2016 |   200    
6  | 15-09-2016 |   200    
7  | 16-09-2016 |   230    
8  | 17-09-2016 |   240
```

and we have to order by date first, and price second, however if the price must be in order. If current price is less than previous we should omit this row, and the result will be:

```
id |    date    | price
------------------------
1  | 10-09-2016 |   200
3  | 12-09-2016 |   210
4  | 13-09-2016 |   220
7  | 16-09-2016 |   230
8  | 17-09-2016 |   240
```

Is it possible without join?

Comment: mysql or postgres?

Comment: `Postgresql` <> `Mysql` are two different db engines which one are you using ?

Comment: does not matter, any solution

Comment: So I can write answer on `Postgresql` which will not even compile on `Mysql`

Comment: please do......

Comment: What if row 6 had price 210? Would it be in the result? IOW: how is "previous" defined exactly? Previous in the input or in the output?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent dbms tags. Feel free to put one of them back.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LAG` window function

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Lag(price)OVER( ORDER BY date) AS prev_price
        FROM   Yourtable) a
WHERE  price > prev_price
        OR prev_price IS NULL -- to get the first record
```

Comment: Nice solution! However shouldn't the ORDER BY clause also contain price?

Answer (score 1):

If "previous" is supposed to mean the previous row in the *output*, then keep track of a running maximum. Postgres solution with a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) in a subquery:

```
SELECT id, date, price
FROM  (
   SELECT *, price >= max(price) OVER (ORDER BY date, price) AS ok
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  ok;
```

Answer (score 0):

If Postgres:

```
select id, date, price
from
(select
    t.*,
    price - lag(price, 1, price) over (order by id) diff
from
    your_table) t
where diff > 0;
```

If MySQL:

```
select id, date, price from
(
    select t.*, 
        price - @lastprice diff,
        @lastprice := price
    from
    (select *
    from your_table
    order by id) t
    cross join (select @lastprice := 0) t2
) t where t.diff > 0;
```